# Select an element of his parent that is not immediately after his parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<div class="form-group well">
    <p>...</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="select-skill">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="select-skill">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="select-skill">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="select-skill">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And i want to set a style using css3 to second child that has `select-skill` class, but i cant use `.select-skill:nth-child(2)`, It doesn't work.

I know the solution is to remove `<p>...</p><h1>` or move `select-skill` to a new parent.

Is there any solution to select this element ***without adding any code of html***?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @torazaburo Im not allowed to change html code. I can change only the css style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyjHD/)

You can use this:

```
.select-skill:nth-of-type(2){
  background:red;
}
```

Or if there are more in different `div`'s, you can do:

```
.form-group .select-skill:nth-of-type(2){
  /*styles*/
}
```

instead.

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. But you might want to also explain a little on "why". Maybe you could use this fiddle to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/bdMAs/

Comment: note that `nth-of-type` works only for type (tagname), the code may confuse some ones because they may think it works for class. Here in this example, if changing the first `.select-skill` element from `div` to `span`, then the targeted element is the second `div` (which is the third div in the original code). http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/EyjHD/1/

Comment: Indeed - I highly recommend qualifying the selector with `div` to make this distinction a little clearer.